# Creating unique order count for duplicate orders by account id and order id

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a data set that will show me the duplicate transactions. The trouble I'm running into is when there are multiple orders on one order_id. The records that get assigned the 2s I would be considering the duplicate order.

```
data have;
input acct_id order_id;
datalines;
1 121
1 122
2 123
2 124
3 125
3 125
3 125
3 126
3 126
3 126

data want;
set have;
by acct_id order_id;
if first.acct_id then order_count = 1;
else order_count =2; 
run;
```

My desired output is below.

```
acct_id | order_id | order_count
1           121       1
1           122       2
2           123       1
2           124       2 
3           125       1
3           125       1
3           125       1
3           126       2
3           126       2
3           126       2
```

What I have coded out already I feel like is close but I can't get it figured out.

Comment: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-create-an-enumeration-variable-by-groups/

Comment: You need either an explicit `RETAIN` or implicit `RETAIN.` The `SUM` statement (order_count+1) is an implicit `RETAIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data want;
  set have;
  by acct_id order_id notsorted;
  if first.acct_id then order_count=0;
  if first.order_id then order_count+1;
  put acct_id order_id order_count;
run;
```

```
acct_id  order_id  order_count
 1        121         1
 1        122         2
 2        123         1
 2        124         2
 3        125         1
 3        125         1
 3        125         1
 3        126         2
 3        126         2
 3        126         2
```